# A single word which means to start a company or business

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the single word which means to start a company or business?

Answer (score 6):

**Establish**: to found, institute, build, or bring into being on a firm or stable basis: to establish a university; to establish a medical practice. ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/establish))

For example, someone discussing their business plans might say "Our goal is to be established by June of this year."

"Ford Motor company was established in Dearborn, Michigan."

Synonym is **found**

Answer (score 6):

Any word for originating a project can be applied to a business: *start*, *create*, etc.

But most commonly, to start an enterprise is to **found** it, and the person who does so is its **founder**. Being named a founder or co-founder of a company has some impact on the allocation of equity of a startup, and there is a small industry in Silicon Valley that connects entrepreneurs with possible co-founders (e.g. mating someone with a great business idea with someone with the technical skills to implement it).

Answer (score 5):

People usually simply *start* or *set up* a company or a business. The company may then be *incorporated*.

[Incorporate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incorporate):

> **2** constitute (a company, city, or other organization) as a legal corporation

Comment: Launch is another one that can be used, though less so.

Comment: Related: The word _start_ is used so often that the word [_start-up_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/startup) is a noun that means "a new business."

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, the word "enterprise", may be used as a transitive verb. 
(*source*, [Webster's Online Dictionary](http://www.totodefinition.com/search.php?word=enterprise))

So you can say, for example, "I will enterprise my business by the end of this month."

Comment: That sentence doesn't sound right. 'Enterprise' is hardly ever used as a verb.

Comment: @Mitch, Click on my link, it supports "enterprise" as a verb. If that link is down, which it might be, try this one: http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=enterprise&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on

Comment: Dictionaries have a hard time giving good frequency information. I'm only one native speaker but your sentence sounds really wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by frequency information? A lot of people would intuitively judge 'hazard a guess' as incorrect sounding, because most people think of hazard as a noun (and it is, of course). But it is in fact, correct usage of the word.

Comment: Frequency information = how common or rare a usage is. Making a verb out of 'enterprise' is rare (I've never heard that before, it sounds wrong, and it would take an excess of confidence of even a native speaker to use it that way).

Comment: I wasn't basing my answer on frequency, and I didn't know that was a prerequisite for an answer on E.SE. I will check the FAQ and About section, and if I find such a rule in there, I will delete my answer. Otherwise, if I honestly thought I was wrong, I would take the question down. Go ahead and vote me down if you honestly believe that is incorrect.

Comment: Ah..those examples (in Webster's)  are pretty dated. they don't even sound erudite, they sound very 'off'.

Comment: Your Webster's link returns an Error 404.

Comment: @ErikKowal thanks, the link should be updated now.

Comment: @ErikKowal For future reference ... links on websites frequently go down. However, links like these are easy to correct, just re-input the word of question into the search-bar (by actually visiting webster's online dictionary) and copy the new link into the answer. You may click on the 'edit' option below my answer, and I will gladly approve the edit the next time around. After all, everyone's questions and answers are property of the community and are subject to revisions.

Answer (score -1):

'Found', 'establish', start up', etc.